# HTTP persistent connection vs Stateless Web

Tags: http, sockets, stateless

If HTTP persistent connection is kept alive and done on the same socket with out dropping a socket or creating a new one for next HTTP connection. Then how come that HTTP is stateless and each HTTP request is on its own when they share the same socket?

Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is considered stateless because the browser sends all the information the server works (cookies, referrer, etc) with in the HTTP Request Headers.

While there might a database involved which does store state, HTTP is stateless, because it doesn't store anything. And even if the socket is kept open, as long as it doesn't store anything it is still considered stateless.